# Laravel 5, debugger not working

Tags: laravel

I recently installed Laravel 5 on my local WAMP server. Firstly I was surprised, because I was expecting the 4.2 Laravel, but as I got the 5th, I decided to give it a try. Firstly I got confused with the folders, but I got used to that and now understand them, but I cannot seem to get my debugger work. In Laravel 4.2 all I had to do was to set `'debug' => true,` in the config/app.php file, and when something went wrong, a nice widow appeared in the browser explaining what was wrong. But now all I get is the default Laravel 5 error page in white n' gray -

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.......

I searched the web for the answer. The possible solutions were to:

1. run the command `php artisan optimize` in the app folder for the vegant box, but I seem to be not using it and if I run artisan command in the app folder, I'm getting an error: count not open an input file: artisan
2. Delete the storage/meta/compiled.php file. The problem here is that I dont have such a file.

So right now I am quite worried, because I can't work without that debugger, especialy when I haven't worked with Laravel for a quite a time.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Might seem a stupid question but do you have debug turned on in your `.env` file? `APP_DEBUG=true`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 uses dotenv. And it is easy to do it

1. In the root folder rename `.env.example` to `.env`  you will see APP_DEBUG=true inside.
2. restart the webserve
3. The debug mode should be enabled right now.

More information http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: There are already both .env and .env.example files in my project folder. So is it okay if the old env.example file is now the new .env file replacing the previous one?

Comment: @user3816142 what is the value of APP_DEBUG in .env file?

Comment: So i just removed the env.example file from the folder, left the .env file in, restarted my server, in the .env file APP_DEBUG is set to true, but still cant get the debug mode

Comment: btw, should I change the database, username and pasword in the .env file to what I set in the database.php file within the 'mysql' in the config folder?

Comment: Yes, you can set the database configuration in `.env`. You can see something like `env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')` in `database.php`. The first parameter will be used first.But if is is not set, the second parameter will be used.

Comment: Thanks for help, did that.
But are there any more ideas about the debugger? I spent yesterday few hours and now today also few. And finally decided to ask here.

Comment: Check the `'debug'` variable in `/config/app.php`, It should be `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),`

Comment: @user3816142, You got the database working by setting `.env`, right?

Comment: actually I got it working by setting the database.php file, i just removed the .env part of the code, it was like : 'database'  => 'database_name'
Thats how I did it in the 4.2 version, thought that this wont change here. 
And about the app.php, debug is set now to `env('APP_DEBUG')` but this wont help

Comment: It seems the `.env` is not working in your environment. Work around you might need to set the value of `debug` in `app.php` to `"true"`. It should look like `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),` Sorry, I could not help you. I have never used it on wamp before. Anyway I suggest you to use [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead) in future development

Comment: Great thanks to you anyway, I never even knew about such a file.
Yeah, setting debug to just true in app.php was my first try :D

Comment: Well, now I think that I could not be more stupid... Does the debugg page in Laravel 5 look something like this?
http://postimg.org/image/t0cr5mizn/

Comment: @user3816142 Yes, That is the error page with debug enable. You got it.

Comment: Ouh, okay, and is there a way I could make it look like it was in Laraval 4.2? I believe back then it was more understandable